# How important is user's feedback to new modules of a site?

Tags: website-design, user-feedback

We have added some new modules into the system which are totally new to the new users as well as existing users. Will it be wise to ask for user's feedback about the newly built modules? What are the best ways to get users' feedback?

Answer (score 2):

It is important to get feedback of course. 
Some ways to do it :

Popup a Customer Survey. Displaying a simple survey on your site is the easiest way to get feedback. ...
Put a Feedback Button on Your Website. ...
Offer an Incentive. ...
Use Live Chat. ...
Monitor Analytics

From here: https://optinmonster.com/best-ways-to-collect-customer-feedback/